# What is cosmic light referred to as?

Tags: scripture, meditation, om, sadhana, cosmology

In his book "God Talks with Arjuna", Paramahansa Yogananda says [this](http://yogananda.com.au/gita/gita0614om.html#cosmic):

> God manifests in creation as the Cosmic Vibration, which expresses itself as Cosmic Sound and Cosmic Light. The **Cosmic Sound or Aum** is the synthesis of all the sounds of the highly vibrating life forces, electrons, protons, and atoms. By listening to Aum, the yogi becomes a true brahmachari or one who is attuned to Brahman. By deep concentration the devotee can hear **Aum** at any time and in any place....
>
> In the Yoga Sutras of Patanjali, **Aum (Om)** is spoken of as the symbol of Ishvara or God. This great authority on yoga refers to **Aum as a Cosmic Sound** continuously flowing in the ether, unutterable by any human voice, and fully known only to the illuminated.

My question: Cosmic sound is referred to as **AUM (OM)** but what is cosmic light referred to as?

Comment: It looks like Yogananda also considers cosmic light to be Om: "The single eye in the forehead of man possesses spherical vision. In meditation that vision gradually expands for the yogi into an ineffable sphere of constantly changing luminosity, blissful and omnipresent. After experiencing this vibratory vision of Aum as the Cosmic Light, the emancipated yogi goes beyond all delusive relativities of vibrations. He then feels and realizes the Transcendental Lord" http://yogananda.com.au/pyr/pyr_eye1.html

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Is the cosmic light the spiritual third eye?

Comment: No, it sounds like Yogananda is saying that the Cosmic Light is a sphere of light that you can see using your spiritual third eye.  In any case, I don't know of a scriptural basis for any of this.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I agree with you, a yogi sees that cosmic light (spiritual third eye) only when he is connected to that cosmic sound AUM

Comment: Again, I don't think Yogananda is equating the cosmic light with the spiritual third eye.  Rather he's saying hat the spiritual third eye is a tool to see the cosmic.

Answer (score 1):

The cosmic light is known as ज्योतिः (Jyotir)

> Netre pasyati jaj **jyoti** staaraarupam prakaashakam/sa jeevah sarvabhutanaam atmaanam cha samaahitah// (Ref:Sanatkumar-Sanhita, Shiva-Puran).

Its also referred to as Bindu, while the sound as "Naada"

> **Naada**-koti-sahasrani **bindu**-koti-satani cha/sarve tat pralayam janti brahma-Pranava-naadake// in Naadavindu-Upanishad 
>   meaning there are crores of types of Vindu and of Naada and all merge in OM (Pranava).

So OM is NOT the only cosmic sound.

(Reference: Anubhava-Sangraha,Dikshaa-Saara, Amita, republished by Mahamilan Math, page 332-347).

Comment: Well Naada we have heard quite often, never heard about Vindu anywhere...!